# How do I retrieve the file name of a google sheets document by using the URL in another Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Example: I have google sheets A titled "Expenses", and google sheet B titled "List"

I want to be able to enter a formula cell A1 in google sheet B, for example googleSheetTitle("google sheets A URL"), so that cell A1 returns "Expenses" (the filename of google sheets A).

So far I have asked ChatGPT for a solution, it gave me the following custom function:

```
function retrieveTitle(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var title = response.getContentText().match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1];
  return title.replace(" - Google Sheets", "").trim();
}
```

However this returns "Google Sheets - create and edit spreadsheets online."
Any ideas, or is it even possible?

Comment: From your showing script, in your situation, the Spreadsheet of `url` is publicly shared?

Answer (score 0):

For this approach to work, you need to make sure that your spreadsheet is available publicly. This is because `UrlFetchApp` in your example is making unauthenticated calls.

To make it work, you would need to use OAuth2 with a user's credentials to do the fetch requests.

However, a simpler solution would be to not use a custom function, but rather call the function below through a custom menu, this way Apps Script will handle the authentication for you.

If you need to make sure it updates the spreadsheet names when they change, you can configure a trigger.

```js
function getName() {
  const sheetUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .prompt('Please enter the URL')
    .getResponseText();

  const sheetName = SpreadsheetApp
    .openByUrl(sheetUrl)
    .getName();

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setValue(sheetName);
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom')
    .addItem('Get Sheet Name', 'getName')
    .addToUi();
}
```

And unfortunately you can't use `SpreadsheetApp` in a custom function, because custom functions don't allow running services that require authentication.